# What's the difference between " It is helpful for you to read English every day." and "It is helpful for you reading English every day."

Tags: difference

> It is helpful for you to read English every day.
>     It is helpful for you reading English every day.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 4):

The difference is just about using an infinitive or a gerund. It sounds more natural to use to + infinitive with the word *helpful*. The Gerund **reading** is  a verbal Noun, so it's better to place it in the beginning of the sentence.

> Reading English every day is helpful for you.